# Error when adding Blog Post page in Umbraco4

Tags: umbraco

I am having troubles adding a new Blog Post to my Umbraco 4 website.  This has been working fine up until recently and not sure what changes would have caused this error.

I have added a new Blog Date Folder and then tried to add the Blog Post but as soon as it navigates to the content editor, I get the following error.

Any ideas?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a property pointing to a node that no longer exists.  Go into the Settings tab and view the properties of your doctype.  Look for the property using the "uComponents XPathDropDownList".

You may have removed or updated a node that one of your property editors was using.